# c++ weird array by user input

Tags: c++, arrays, dev-c++

As I know in c++ if you want to crete an array, you must give constant value for its size. But here:

```
int main(){

    int a;
    cin >> a;
    int b[a] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i<a ; i++){
        b[i] = a;
        cout << b[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If i input 5

**output:**

```
55555
```

It works fine in a way i can't understand in dev c++. If i run this in visual studio 2017, it gives error. Can anyone explanin why?

Comment: Variable Length Arrays are not standard C++ if you can use them then they are an extension of the compiler you are using.

Comment: Related: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/2602718)

Answer (score 0):

> As I know in c++ if you want to crete an array, you must give constant value for its size.

Correct. If you use a non-constant value, then the program is ill-formed. Yes, the program that you show is ill-formed.

> It works fine in a way i can't understand ... Can anyone explanin why?

C++ compiler may allow compilation of an ill-formed program. This enables the compilers to extend the language. It appears that you were using a non-standard extension to C++.

This is what the GCC compiler says about your program:

> ```
> warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'b' [-Wvla]
> int b[a] = {};
>        ^
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using GCC by any chance? This is a GCC extension and it's enable by default. In fact it's quite a dangerous one because it's fairly easy to cause a stack overflow on your program. It's roughly the same as using [`alloca()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html).

In order to disable it, you should use a compiler flag called `-Wpedantic`. This will make your compiler issue a warning. ([see this demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/ld8Fy3))

> ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘b’ [-Werror=vla]